# PHP: saving multiple tuples to the same table

Tags: php, insert

I am trying to save data into the same table several times from the same $_POST array. You see, on my registration form a family is allowed to specify the names, gender and age of all members they wish to bring along.

This data is being stored in a database table called aditional_member. Based on family size, I am dynamically generating html table rows where each row has the number of input fields required.

```
<tr id="additionalmember_3">
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name1" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name1" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
    td><select name="gender1" value="" ><option value='Male'>Male</option><option value='Female'>Female</option></select></td>
    <td><select name="age_group"value="" ><option value='18 to 30'>18 to 30</option><option value='31 to 60'>31 to 60</option></select></td>      
</tr>
```

When I POST, let us say I have three sets of input(3 table rows as above), Is there a simple way to insert into the addional_member table the data from row one, then row two, and so on. I tried looping the insert statement, which failed. I am basically open to suggestions, I do not need to use a table.

Any ideas,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you want, but try this

```
    <?php
    //having 3 rows to insert 
    for($i=1;$i<4;$i++){

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (field1, field2, field3) values (
          '".$_POST['first_name'.$i]."',
          '".$_POST['last_name'.$i]."',
          '".$_POST['gender'.$i]."')");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Changing the `name` of the inputs to have `[]` at the end will cause PHP to treat the `$_POST` elements as an array. Just iterate over the indexes and pull from each array together.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "[]" feature of PHP to pass your post documents an array, so your rows will look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name[]" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name[]" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
    <td><select name="gender[]" value="" >
           <option value='Male'>Male</option>
           <option value='Female'>Female</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="age_group[]" value="" >
           <option value='18 to 30'>18 to 30</option>
           <option value='31 to 60'>31 to 60</option>
        </select>
    </td>      
</tr>
```

When you get the submitted data, just use `print_r()` to dump it to the screen and you'll see how it's organized for you.